# MATLAB Invalid MEX File

Tags: macos, matlab, shared-libraries, 32bit-64bit, mex

So I'm running software I downloaded for analyzing the position of fluorescent proteins in microscopy images.  The software is called [plusTipTracker](http://lccb.hms.harvard.edu/software.html), and it runs off MATLAB.

So the first function (detecting 'spots' in the images) works fine, but the second function ("track spots") fails.  In particular, it seems to be an error with a MEX file:

```
??? Invalid MEX-file
'/Users/ethanbuchman/Documents/MATLAB/plusTipTracker_1pt1pt3_2012-07-07/software/createDistanceMatrix.mexmaci64':
dlopen(/Users/ethanbuchman/Documents/MATLAB/plusTipTracker_1pt1pt3_2012-07-07/software/createDistanceMatrix.mexmaci64,
1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/ethanbuchman/Documents/MATLAB/plusTipTracker_1pt1pt3_2012-07-07/software/createDistanceMatrix.mexmaci64:
        unknown required load command 0x80000022.
```

I can locate this file in the software folder i downloaded.  There are actually multiple versions, each with a different extension (eg. .mexa64, .mexmaci, .mexmaci64, etc.).  There's also a .dll file.  While there are other mex files in the folder, each with multiple extensions, none of the others have an associated dll file. Not sure if that's relevant.

But I have no idea what to do about this.

Im on MacOSX 10.5.8 using Matlab R2010b.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you're using 64bit matlab and Mac OSX?

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm reading [here](http://asqueella.blogspot.com/2010/12/dyld-unknown-required-load-command.html), it seems like the MEX file was compiled for a different version of Mac OS. Can you recompile the MEX files and DLL on your own system?

Comment: that sounds right.  how can i go about that?  i dont have the original source code, only the mex file.

Comment: You could try moving all the .mex*64 files out of your path so that matlab will run the 32-bit versions... Some of what I'm reading says that the 10.6 specific features should only be used by 64-bit binaries.

Comment: ok.  i tried movin the file (.mexmaci64) out of the path.  but now I just get:??? Undefined function or method 'createDistanceMatrix' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: Unless you feel like upgrading your OS, the only other thing I can think of is to email the authors and request either the source or a version for 10.5. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: mmmm ok.  i was afraid that might be the case.  thanks for your help.